# Hibernate fetching in criteria ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, fetching-strategy

I have some class User which has one to many relation to LoginSession class (I have a collection of LoginSessions in my User class).

```
@Entity(name="T_User")
public class User() 
{
   ....
     @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
     @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
     @JsonIgnore
     private Set<LoginSession> userLoginSession;
   ....
 }
```

Here is the LoginSession class:

```
@Entity(name="T_LoginSession")
public class LoginSession extends BasicDTO
{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")  
    protected User user;
    ...
```

And I have this Criteria:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
crit.setFetchMode("loginSession", FetchMode.JOIN);
crit.createAlias("userLoginSession", "session");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("session.token", sessionToken));
crit.setMaxResults(1);
crit.setFirstResult(0);
crit.setFetchSize(1);
```

The problem is that the fetching is always Lazy. How can I make it to be Eager (via criteria and not via attribute annotation)?

**Note:**
If I am adding `@Fetch` annotation above the `private Set<LoginSession> userLoginSession` the response fetching as set in the annotation (I wont it to be customised by the criteria `setFetchMode`).

**Are the names of the fields (the first parameter of the `setFetchMode` method) correct?**

**Question:**
[Is this bug related to my issue?](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6405)

Comment: check this 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823552/hibernate-eager-loading-with-query

Comment: @Killer, I don't see how it helps me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9931401/671619) you can not filter and eager fetch a collection at the same time. you can solve it with a correlated subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.For(User.class)
    .createAlias("userLoginSession", "session")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("session.token", sessionToken))
    .setFirstResult(0)
    .setMaxResults(1)     // assuming token is unique otherwise this won't restrict users but loginsessions
    .setProjection(Projections.id());

Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .add(Subqueries.propertyIn("id", subquery)
    .setFetchMode("userLoginSession", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

Note: this is text editor code of the top of my head. Methodnames may vary

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 Criteria crt = session.createCriteria(User.class);
 crt.setFetchMode("sessions", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

Comment: Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("sessions", FetchMode.JOIN);
List list = criteria.list();

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
crit.setFetchMode("session.userId", FetchMode.EAGER);
User myThingy = (User)crit.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: EAGER is deprecated, according documentation I need to use JOIN.

Comment: Ok, are you getting unexpected results or some exceptions. What's going wrong? How are you testing your code?

Comment: The setFetchingMethod doing nothing. That is the problem. I see that I am having one query when I am getting the user (as seen in the code) and another one when I am accessing the relationship.

Comment: Do you use annotations for mapping?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the jointype on the alias:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
crit.createAlias("userLoginSession", "session", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("session.token", sessionToken));
crit.setMaxResults(1);
crit.setFirstResult(0);
crit.setFetchSize(1);
```

Comment: this is deprecated :(

Comment: What is deprecated? In the stable release, you can use createAlias(String associationPath, alias, joinType) (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.hibernate.sql.JoinType))

Comment: I am using hibernate 4 and eclipse indicates that is deprecated. Can you look at the names I provided as strings to setFetchingMethod?