# Fetch subclass with Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to get 'Object' (which is a row in my db) using Hibernae. The 'Object' is referenced in the db by 'Nofitication'. 'Notification' contains  a row that is referenced to 'Object'.

My problem is that the object has also subclass, and i want to get the full subclass while i'm only getting the lazy Object.
Here is my code:

```
public ScrollableResults getScrollableObjects(Transaction transaction, NotificationAttributes notificationAttributes) {
    Criteria criteria = transaction.getSession().createCriteria(Notification.class);
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("object"));
    criteria.add(Property.forName("name").eq(notificationAttributes.getName()));
    criteria.createAlias("object", "object",     CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
    ScrollableResults scroll = criteria.setFetchSize(1000).scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    return scroll;
}
```

Any Suggestions on how can i solve it? Thanks.

Comment: See: [Hibernate fetching in criteria ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841292/hibernate-fetching-in-criteria-ignored)

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this example

```
Criteria person = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Person.class).createAlias("personId", "personId");

person.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.ilike("PersonFirstname",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Jacket",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Color",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Restrictions.ilike("personId.Size",Search,MatchMode.ANYWHERE)));
```